# javascript implementation of lodash "set" method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Found [this excellent code](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore) for `_.get` vanilla js implementation:

```
const get = (obj, path, defaultValue) => path.split(".")
.reduce((a, c) => (a && a[c] ? a[c] : (defaultValue || null)), obj)
```

Now I'm looking for `_.set` implementation, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could simply copy *lodash* source code methods.. import lodash. use `get`, and copy the transpiled code

Comment: I believe this implementation of `_.get` is oversimplified and would not work e.g. with array indices or array/quoted notation of object properties. So you can't write `get("a.b[3].c['prop']")`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this could cover it:

```js
const set = (obj, path, value) => {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return obj; // When obj is not an object
    // If not yet an array, get the keys from the string-path
    if (!Array.isArray(path)) path = path.toString().match(/[^.[\]]+/g) || []; 
    path.slice(0,-1).reduce((a, c, i) => // Iterate all of them except the last one
         Object(a[c]) === a[c] // Does the key exist and is its value an object?
             // Yes: then follow that path
             ? a[c] 
             // No: create the key. Is the next key a potential array-index?
             : a[c] = Math.abs(path[i+1])>>0 === +path[i+1] 
                   ? [] // Yes: assign a new array object
                   : {}, // No: assign a new plain object
         obj)[path[path.length-1]] = value; // Finally assign the value to the last key
    return obj; // Return the top-level object to allow chaining
};

// Demo
var obj = { test: true };
set(obj, "test.1.it", "hello");
console.log(obj); // includes an intentional undefined value
```

It is a bit more complex than `get`, because there is some logic needed to create missing parts of the path in the object, to overwrite primitive values that stand in the way, and to determine whether a new child should better be an array or a plain object.

Answer (score 4):

Check this one:

```
/**
 * @example
 * const obj = {id:1, address: {city: 'Minsk', street: 'Prityckogo 12'}}
 * setByString(obj, 'address.city', 'Grodno'); obj.address.city => 'Grodno'
 * setByString(obj, ['address', 'city'], 'Grodno'); obj.address.city => 'Grodno'
 * setByString(obj, ['address', 'city', 'phones'], {mobile: 1234, home: 222}); obj.address.city.phones.home => 222
*/

/**
* @param    {any}   input
* @return   {boolean}
*/

const isObject = (input) => (
  null !== input && 
    typeof input === 'object' &&
    Object.getPrototypeOf(input).isPrototypeOf(Object)
)

 **/
 * @param   {object}    obj
 * @param   {string}    path
 * @param   {any}       value
 */

const setByString = (obj, path, value) => {
  const pList = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split('.');
  const len = pList.length;
  // changes second last key to {}
  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    const elem = pList[i];
    if (!obj[elem] || !isObject(obj[elem])) {
      obj[elem] = {};
    }
    obj = obj[elem];
  }

  // set value to second last key
  obj[pList[len - 1]] = value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const set = (obj = {}, paths = [], value) => {
    const inputObj = obj === null ? {} : { ...obj };

    if (paths.length === 0) {
        return inputObj;
    }

    if (paths.length === 1) {
        const path = paths[0];
        inputObj[path] = value;
        return { ...inputObj, [path]: value };
    }

    const [path, ...rest] = paths;
    const currentNode = inputObj[path];

    const childNode = set(currentNode, rest, value);

    return { ...inputObj, [path]: childNode };
};
```

Example:
const input = {};

set(input, ['a', 'b'], 'hello');

Result:
{ a: { b: 'hello' }}

Comment: nice recursive approach. can't you do without the additional spread on return? since you are already shallow coping on each set call? so just return the set inputObj:
`if (paths.length === 1) {
    const path = paths[0];
    inputObj[path] = value;
    return inputObj;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of lodash 'get' and 'set' without using dot or bracket notation; useful for passing security scans.

https://jsfiddle.net/5amtL8zx/17/

```
/* lodash implementation of 'get', 'set', and 'unset' without dot or bracket notation
  * - supports getting and setting 'prop1.2' array element but not with brackets: 'prop1.[2]'
  */
isObjectKey = (obj, key) => {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype && /string|number/.test(typeof key);
}

isArrayNumber = (obj, key) => {
  const isKey = /string|number/.test(typeof key), path = isKey ? String(key).split('.') : [], prop = isKey && path.length > 1 ? path.shift() : '';
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Array.prototype && isKey && !isNaN(prop);
}

isValid = (obj, key) => {
  const isObj = isObjectKey(obj, key), isArr = isArrayNumber(obj, key);
  return isObj || isArr;
}

define = (obj, key, value) => {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, String(key), { value, writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: true  });
}

get = (obj, key, value) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = String(key).split('.'), prop = path.shift(), result = new Map(Object.entries(obj)).get(prop);
  return path.length && typeof result !== 'undefined' ? get(result, path.join('.'), value) : result || value;
}

set = (obj, key, value) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = key.split('.'), prop = path.shift();
  if (!(prop in obj)) {
    define(obj, prop, {});
  }
  const result = get(obj, prop);
  return path.length && isValid(result, path.join('.')) ? set(result, path.join('.'), value) : define(obj, prop, value);
}

unset = (obj, key) => {
  if (!isValid(obj, key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let path = key.split('.'), prop = path.shift();
  if (!(prop in obj)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (path.length) {
    let result = get(obj, prop);
    result = unset(result, path.join('.'));
    set(obj, prop, result);
    return obj;
  } else {
    const { [prop]: remove, ...rest } = obj;
    return rest;
  }
}

let obj = {};
set(obj, 'prop1.prop2', 'value1');
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
console.log(get(obj, 'prop1.prop2'));
const prop1 = get(obj, 'prop1');
set(prop1, 'prop2', 'value2');
console.log(get(obj, 'prop1.prop2'));
set(obj, 'prop3', [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3'));
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3.2'));
console.log(get(obj.prop3, 0));
set(obj, 'prop3.3', 4);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop3.3'));
set(obj, 'prop4', [{'name': 'Bob'}]);
console.log(get(obj, 'prop4.0'));
unset(obj, 'prop4.0.name')
console.log(get(obj, 'prop4.0'));
//[["prop1", {
//  prop2: "value1"
//}]]
//"value1"
//"value2"
//[1, 2, 3]
//3
//1
//4
//{
//  name: "Bob"
//}
//{ ... }
```