# Is there any method to change the value of n-th depth value?

Tags: javascript, json, object

For example, I have data like this

```
data = {
    code:1,
    status: 200,
    data:[{
        name: {
            first: 'first',
            last: 'last',
        },
        age: 12,
        address: "address",
        ...
    },
    ...
    ,{
        ...
    }]
}

key = 'data[0].name.last';
```

I want to change the value `data.data[0].name.last` and I know last value's path(key) is `data[0].name.last`.

`data[key] = 'last1'` doesn't work because of array index.
Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Try eval? Although that isn't the best way.

Comment: Maybe `const value="last1";
eval(key+'"'+value.replace(/"/g,'\\"')+'"')`

Comment: I'd just use Lodash ~ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

Comment: if you dont want the whole lodash https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.set . here is the source https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/set.js .  a solution here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733539/javascript-implementation-of-lodash-set-method