# How to set values in JavaScript objects using dynamic path strings or arrays, with support for pushing values into arrays and specifying indices?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to create a function in JavaScript that allows me to set values in nested objects using dynamic path strings or arrays. The path strings may include indices to specify the exact location where the value should be set. Additionally, the path strings can include "[]" notation to push values into arrays.

For instance, given an object like:

```js
const obj = { foo: { bar: [] } };
```

I want to set a value at the path `"foo.bar[][2]"` or `"foo.bar[2][]".`

The function should be able to handle both string and array representations of the path.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```js
setValue(obj, 'foo.bar[][2]', 'value');
console.log(obj); // Output: { foo: { bar: [[ <2 empty items>, 'value' ] ] } }

setValue(obj, 'foo.bar[2][]', 'value');
console.log(obj); // Output: { foo: { bar: [ <2 empty items> , [ 'value' ] ] } }
```

How can I implement such a function efficiently in JavaScript?

Comment: what represents the first string? plase add some examples. what have you tried?

Comment: What's your question? If there's no library that does it, you'll need to write it yourself. What do you need from us?

Comment: "I want" is not a question.

Comment: I tried for two days now and i couldn't write it myself. My last hope for help is here.

Comment: Please provide examples of input and expected output (in JavaScript notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could take the lodash-style `set` function, but modify it to deal with `[]` as a an indication to push a value to an array (if it is an array).

Drawing on the `set` function provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54733755/5459839), it could be this:

```js
function setValue(obj, path, value) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return obj;
    if (!Array.isArray(path)) path = path.toString().match(/[^.[\]]+|(?<=\[)(?=])/g) || []; 
    const a = path.slice(0,-1).reduce((a, c, i) => {
         if (Array.isArray(a) && !c) c = a.length;
         return Object(a[c]) === a[c] 
             ? a[c] 
             : a[c] = !path[i+1] || Math.abs(path[i+1])>>0 === +path[i+1] ? [] : {}
    }, obj);
    let c = path.at(-1);
    if (Array.isArray(a) && !c) c = a.length;
    a[c] = value;
    return obj;
}

// Demo
const obj = { foo: { bar: [] } };
setValue(obj, 'foo.bar[][2]', 'value');
console.log(obj); // Output: { foo: { bar: [[ <2 empty items>, 'value' ] ] } }
const obj2 = { foo: { bar: [] } };
setValue(obj2, 'foo.bar[2][]', 'value');
console.log(obj2); // Output: { foo: { bar: [ <2 empty items> , [ 'value' ] ] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create your own mixin to split the path, retrieve the existing value, and push a new value.

You will need a bit of RegExp-fu to check the incoming path.

```js
const state = { foo: { bar: [] } }

_.mixin({
  setValue: function(obj, path, val) {
    let match, full, subpath, index, arr;
    
    // Check for: [][INDEX]
    match = path.match(/(.+)\[\]\[(\d+)\]$/);
    if (match) {
      [full, subpath, index] = match, arr = _.get(obj, subpath, []);
      arr[+index] = val; // Assign value to index
      _.set(obj, subpath, [arr]); // Set as sub-array
      return;
    }
    
    // Check for: [INDEX][]
    match = path.match(/(.+)\[(\d+)\]\[\]$/);
    if (match) {
      [full, subpath, index] = match, arr = _.get(obj, subpath, []);
      arr[+index] = [val]; // Assign sub-array to index
       _.set(obj, subpath, arr); // Set as existing array
       return;
    }
  }
});

const scenarioA = _.cloneDeep(state);
_.setValue(scenarioA, 'foo.bar[][2]', 'value');
console.log(scenarioA); // { foo: { bar: [[, , "value"]] }}

const scenarioB = _.cloneDeep(state);
_.setValue(scenarioB, 'foo.bar[2][]', 'value');
console.log(scenarioB); // { foo: { bar: [, , ["value"]] }}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```